# Intellij plugin development, SDK source file content

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I can't figure out how to add the Intellij SDK plugin development source files to be able to navigate the files.

Right now I am only getting a decompiled list. I'd like the comments as well.

[image]

Note, I know there is https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/actions/

But shouldn't these already be included?

Can someone explain how to add the sources? I tried from module settings but couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're developing a plugin, or viewing/modifying an existing one, I suggest you take a look at the [IntelliJ SDK docs](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/index.html), especially the [prerequisites](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/prerequisites.html) section, which explains how to set up a proper development environment.

Basically, you should clone IntelliJ community using

```
git clone git://git.jetbrains.org/idea/community.git idea
```

Then configure an IntelliJ SDK, and in the `Sourcepath` tab, add the local git repo to attach the source code.

Comment: Yes, but that is not actually the sources I am devoping against. It would be a lot more userfriendly if they would just ship this, so one doesn't have to figure it out, clone git repos, figure out where to place the sources in a consitent locaion and so on. It would be a lot easier if one could just start developing a plugin right off. Don't you agree?

Comment: Usually I check out the closest tag I can find to the currently installed version (like `idea/142.3728`), I agree this is not the easiest way, but it works. And it's the only way :)

Comment: @momo The IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition source code archive is roughly 75M. Are you suggesting that the size of every download should be increased by 75M so that the 0.1% of users who might be interested in plugin development should have to do one less step in their setup procedure?

Comment: @yole maybe, at least some things could be made simpler. automcatic git or download, sdk already configured when doing new project.